# How to collect corpus from a website using Perl

Tags: perl, cgi-bin

I am searching for a program that collects the all corpus from a website and writes it to a single text file.
I have the following code right now

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

use CGI;
use Cwd;
use strict;
$q=new CGI;
$a=$q->param('file');
chomp($a);
print "$a<br>";
my $ftpname="www.kuvempu.com";
system("wget --mirror -p --convert-links -x --reject=gif $ftpname");
```

But it only gives the .html files of the website. How can I extract only the text from those files and write it to a single text file?

Comment: Check [HTML::Strip](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Strip) or [HTML::FormatText](http://p3rl.org/HTML::FormatText).

Comment: Also, familiarize yourself with what a robots.txt file is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Strip;
use LWP::Simple qw/get/;


my $html = get shift or die "Unable to get web content.";
print HTML::Strip->new()->parse($html);
```

Command-line usage: `perl script.pl http://www.website.com > outFile.txt`

`outFile.txt` will contain the site's corpus.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but when i run on www.kuvempu.com is showing unable to get web content. its not working well

Comment: @user3395299 - The only text on that site is "English Website".  [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) was able to capture that text, but it requires using FireFox and installing/activating a plugin.